# Internet speed test and actual speed don’t seem to match up?

Tags: internet, download, connection

I’ve having this problem with my PC.

On internet speed test says 512.23Mbps (download) and 926.79Mbps (upload).

But when trying to download a game or any file larger than 1GB it doesn’t go up more than 5Mbps.

What could be the problem?

Comment: in simple terms: the speed between you and where you download from is limited to the slowest point in the chain

Comment: Seems like your ISP is throttling you.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often, no matter how fast your connection is - the *other* side is the bottleneck. While my network is fully gigabit to the wall or better, the site you're downloading from may not be able to do your 'full' speed to every user *or* your ISP's interconnect to other networks may be limited.

In my experience with my *current* ISP - I can nearly saturate my connection from, say steam , but not Epic or GOG Galaxy.

Some ISPs also 'lie' and de-throttle while doing speed tests.

You are *very rarely* going to hit the speeds you hit on the benchmark, and end to end connectivity is not just dependant on you.